# Redirect subdomain to primary domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I am trying to do a redirect for my website so that if someone types, for example, `fr.example.com/blabla`, it would redirect them to `example.com/fr/blabla`.

After searching the web, I've found the following that I can put into my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fr\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/fr/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now this redirect is working, however, it seems to ignore the path that is at the end of the URL and alays redirect to example.com/fr/index.php.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you refer to by "whatever is at the end of the URL"? This rule certainly will preserve the _path_ of the URL...

Comment: And a general remark: it should be `^fr\.example\.com$`...

Comment: @arkascha Yes, the path is what I meant, my apologies.

Currently, it is redirecting fr.example.com/fr/path to example.com/fr/index.php, no matter the path

Comment: That means that some other rewriting or redirecting rules interferes.

Comment: @arkascha that is what I was suspecting. Is there an easy way to verify that?

Comment: Well, you already have a verification, I'd say: the posted rule does _not_ implement the redirection you stated, so something else has to perform it. It could be another dynamic configuration file (".htaccess") on either http host, maybe in a different folder, a similar rule implemented in the actual http server's host configuration (where such rules actually belong) or it may even be the application logic itself performing such a redirection.